# Margin behavior in ios

Tags: html, css, containers, margin

could you please tell me whether there is any difference in `margin` understanding in ios? Or is this just a mistake in my CSS I cannot see?
On this link http://www.ottovo-nakladatelstvi.cz/inpage/zoom2d/ I have a `div` with `img`. By pushing `margin` on `:hover`, I tried to create a zoom effect within `div .mg`and it works in Chrome and in IE, but when I use iphone 6s with ios 9.2.1 the picture rolls down (as if the container was adjusting itself) and the left margin is coming from left as a white space.
(I understand :hover on ios is not the best, it is for testing purposes)

```
.mg-image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 5s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 5s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 5s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 5s linear;
    max-width: 200%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.mg-image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.5);
     margin-left: 200px;
}

.mg {
  width:800px;
  height:450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Safari browser ?

Comment: yes, it works on newest and older Safari in osx and it works on IE 10